# Can you change the primary sharepoint online name?

Tags: sharepoint-online

Can you change the primary name in the Sharepoint Online website

Example HotDogLand.Sharepoint.com to Hamburgerville.Sharepoint.com?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- You can’t rename the onmicrosoft domain after sign-up. For example,
  if the initial domain you chose was fourthcoffee.onmicrosoft.com, you
  can’t change it to be fabrikam.onmicrosoft.com. To use a different
  onmicrosoft.com domain, you’d have to start a new subscription with
  Office 365.
- You can’t rename your team site URL. Your team site URL is based on
  your onmicrosoft.com domain name, and because of the way SharePoint
  Online architecture works, unfortunately you can't rename the team
  site.

Here is the thread.

https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/uspartner_ts2team/2017/05/11/can-i-change-my-onmicrosoft-com-domain-name/